# Updating or Replacing object in iCarousel

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm using a iCarousel, if you haven't seen the iCarousel,its an open source project at github: [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

This is how I remove my object at my `iCarousel` :

```
NSInteger index = carousel1.currentItemIndex;
[carousel1 removeItemAtIndex:index animated:YES];
[items1 removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

It says in the methods included in the project that:

```
- (void)removeItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

> This removes an item from the carousel. The remaining items will slide
>   across to fill the gap. Note that the data source is not automatically
>   updated when this method is called, so a subsequent call to reloadData
>   will restore the removed item.

So what I wanted to do Is whenever I remove an item at that index, I want to replace with a [NSNull null] or a dummy object, that can't be seen in the iCarousel to remain the index count of the array. But in my project it seems to be crashing. So I think it isn't possible.
So what I wanted to is update its array or replace an object inside my `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Didn't fully understand what or why you want. But the source code for iCarousel is not very big, you could change it so you get whatever behaviour you want.

Comment: What I want is when I remove an object at index, i want to replace with a nil or a dummy that can't be seen to maintain its index count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform the

```
- (void)removeItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Remove the object from the array before reloading the data. So in that case, your array count remains correct